# Copying images from various directories AsciiDoctor gradle

Tags: gradle, asciidoctor

I have a simple question (documentation does not seem to provide a straightforward answer).

I am trying to copy over various resources (images in this case) while running an asciidoctor gradle task.

The directory structure is not the best, meaning that the adoc files and the assorted images are not logically placed but this is something that I cannot change.

I am trying to find a why to do so and I stumbled across the resources option of asciidoctor. Now my main question is how can I configure it correctly in order for it go through all the directories in the base directory and copy over whatever is not a .adoc file over to the target directory (while maintaining the same folder structure)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably you don't need it anymore, but for anyone interested:

The solution is now described in ['Processing Auxiliary Files'](https://asciidoctor.github.io/asciidoctor-gradle-plugin/development-3.x/user-guide/#_processing_auxiliary_files) section of Asciidoctor Gradle plugin docs.

Here you can see example:

```
resources {
    from(sourceDir) {
        include 'images/**'
        include 'resources/**'
        include 'some_dir/**/*.png'
        exclude 'other_dir/**/notThisOne.png'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gradle-script anyway, you could use gradles copy task. Just define all sources of your images and copy them to one directory.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html

Comment: I wanted to this with the functionality provided by AsciiDoctor itself (something that I did manage to do in the end). 

Problem was that the 'exclude' function seemed not to work OK, so I circumvented this by using the 'include' function